# Is there any general function $x(t)$ that gives the solution to $x''(t) = k/x(t)^2$, where k is a constant?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In physics class, I  often come across various inverse square law equations like the following:

- $F_G= G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$
- $F_E = k_e\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$

Specifically, we are typically given problems involving one fixed body and one body that interacts with that body over a one-dimensional axis (in a manner given by one of the above laws). Thus, the acceleration at any given time of the free body can be modeled by the following differential equation, where the masses/charges/physical constants involved collapse into a single value, k. (This physics stuff is just included for some context.)

- $x''(t)=\frac{k}{x(t)^2}$

However, my exact mathematical question is, given any initial conditions for x(0) and x'(0), is there a general solution to the above equation?  **In short, tell me about solving the subsequent equations for x(t)** please.

- $x(0) = \mathrm{some\, initial\, value} $
- $x'(0) = \mathrm{some\, initial\, value} $
- $x''(t) = \frac{k}{x(t)^2} $, where k is a constant

Again -- please help,

A Curious Calculus Student Who Doesn't Know Much

*P.S. Additionally, how does the sign of k -- whether the force is attractive or repulsive -- affect the result?*

Comment: 2nd order DE, nonlinear. You can solve it but it will be very difficult. What physics are you in?

Comment: Try asking this question in http://physics.stackexchange.com/, I am sure they have the solution and they can help you much faster. This equation can be solved but my solution is not looking so nice and it is just too tedious to write (poor LaTeX skills :-( ).

Comment: was wrong, wouldn't be too tedious too write, if I use my head properly... this might help you-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584554/free-fall-according-to-newtons-gravitation-law

Comment: Thank you... and AP Physics C

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/can-this-gravitational-field-differential-equation-be-solved-or-does-it-not-sho

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107995/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$ (x')^2 + \dfrac{2k}{x(t)}$ is constant (in physical terms, that is conservation of energy).  Call that constant $ E$.  Then
$$ x' = \pm \sqrt{E - \dfrac{2k}{x}}$$
 Note also that $E - 2k/x \ge 0$ for the square root to be real.  The differential equation is separable, and so we get
$$ \int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{E - 2k/x}} = \pm t + C $$
The integral can actually be done in closed form, but is messy: if $E > 0$ it is
$$ 
{\frac {1}{{E}^{3/2}} \left( k\ln  \left( {\frac {Ex+\sqrt {x \left( E
x-2\,k \right) E}-k}{\sqrt {E}}} \right) +\sqrt {x \left( Ex-2\,k
 \right) E} \right) }
$$

Comment: Thank you VERY much... but is there any way to solve this equation for x(t) from t(x)?

Comment: No, there is no closed form for $x$ as a function of $t$.