# Newton's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

As we all know one of Issac Newton's many achievement was to use his theory of gravitation and his law of motion to determine the way the planets move. I am looking for a not too deep resource in which the differential equation which Newton gave is explained together with the solution. It should be using modern notation.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1781/36530.

Comment: This question is better asked in [Physics.SE].